# Request API POST

Tags: python, api

I'm having a problem with a Python request, where I pass the body url to the API data.

Note: I have a Node.js project with TypeScript that works normally, prints to the screen and returns values. However if I try to make a request in Python it doesn't work with an error 401.

Below is an example of how the request is made in Python. can you help me?

```
import requests

url = 'https://admins.exemple'

bodyData = {
    'login': 'admins',
    'pass': 'admin',
    'id': '26' }

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=bodyData)

data = resp.status_code

print(data)
```

Comment: It looks like you are not correctly authenticating with the backend. You need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Please dump a dict to a json string as follows:

```
import json

resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(bodyData))
```

You also can pass your dict to `json` kwarg

```
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=bodyData)
```

It will set `Content-Type: application/json` and dump dict to json automatically

Comment: "I have just checked it out" Did you do `requests.get()` or `requests.post()`?

Comment: "If you need that header set and you don’t want to encode the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly using the json parameter" This is what I was thinking of...which looks like you addressed in your edit.

Comment: I'm cleaning up the comments here. I'm still not convinced that this will solve the 401 response. We don't have enough information about how authentication and authorization works in the system the OP is using.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
I used it this way.
import json

resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(bodyData))


As the api returned the data in text (csv) and not in json I didn't get to use it.

Comment: @WillistonSousaNunes As sudden_appearances says, you can replace `data=json.dumps(bodyData))` with `json=bodyData`.

Comment: it's returning the data on screen and presents a json decoder failure, as I understand it has some null fields in what the api returns and that's why this error.  but if I have to do anything, the error continues or it doesn't bring the data, it's looking for a way.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly authenticating with the server. Usually, you need to send the username and password to a "sign in" route which will then return a token. Then you pass the token with other requests to get authorization. Since I don't know any details about your server and API, I can't provide any more details to help you out.

Comment: As credentials are correct, because I have an automation that runs on top of this api however the same and nodejs, I need to do it in python due to the ease of integrating with powerbi